# Retrieve data from Android Firebase , display it to a listview and apply onItemClickListener to the ListView

Tags: firebase, android-studio, listview

I am new to Android Development.

I want to retrieve all the titles(`Title 1, Title 2, Title 3, Title 4`) from Firebase and display in a `listview` which I am able to do. But I want to apply `onItemClickListener` to the `listview` and I want that when I click a particular item in `listview` the next activity should show me the particular content.
eg if I click `Title 1` then the next activity should display `Content 1`. If `Title 2` then `Content 2`.

Please show how can I do this.`

```
advaitavedanta-f1443
Chapter 1
description: "Content 1"
title: "Title 1"
Chapter 2
description: "Content 2"
title: "Title 2"
Chapter 3
description: "Content 3" 
title: "Title 3"
Chapter 4
description: "Content 4"
title: "Title 4"
//this is my data from firebase//



private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
private FirebaseDatabase mDatabase;
private DatabaseReference mDbRef;

String Title;
String Description;
ListView listView;
ArrayList<String> mybook = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;
Firebase url;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    mDbRef = mDatabase.getReference("Chapter 1");
    User user = new User("Title 1", "Content 1");
    mDbRef.setValue(user);

    mDbRef = mDatabase.getReference("Chapter 2");
    user = new User("Title 2", "Content 2");
    mDbRef.setValue(user);

    mDbRef = mDatabase.getReference("Chapter 3");
    user = new User("Title 3", "Content 3");
    mDbRef.setValue(user);

    mDbRef = mDatabase.getReference("Chapter 4");
    user = new User("Title 4", "Content 4");
    mDbRef.setValue(user);

    Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);

    listView =  findViewById(R.id.listView);
    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, notes);
    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    url = new Firebase("https://advaitavedanta-f1443.firebaseio.com/");

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainContent.class);
            intent.putExtra("noteId", Description);

        }
    });
    url.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            Title = dataSnapshot.child("title").getValue(String.class);
            mybook.add(Title);
            Description = dataSnapshot.child("description").getValue(String.class);

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

}`

Comment: You have posted the code that you have, but what exactly is the problem that you are receiving? Is the code not working? **What's the problem?**

Comment: I am getting the data in listview but I am not getting the data when I click on any item. The next activity is blank. I want to know that when I click on any item in listview it should display corresponding content in next activity( suppose I click ' title 1' next activity should show 'content 1' . Please see the firebase data at top.

Comment: Ok. I know how to get this working. Create your own Adapter class and inside the `getView` method of your Adapter class, set the stuff in the `onClickListener`. You will also need to require the application context as one of the constructor's parameters.

Comment: [This article](https://medium.com/mindorks/custom-array-adapters-made-easy-b6c4930560dd) explains very well how to make a custom adapter class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using `User` object in adding firebase data, use list of user object in retrieving it on your child added.

Make a list of users

```
ArrayList<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
```

Then on your child added do this

```
String title = dataSnapshot.child("title").getValue(String.class);
String description= dataSnapshot.child("description").getValue(String.class);
users.add(new User(title, description));
```

Then finally, on your list click modify the extra

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainContent.class);
intent.putExtra("content_description", users.get(position).getDescription());
startActivity(intent);
```

**Note:** You could also put the whole object in the intent but you need to make`User` object implement parcelable.

**Suggestion:** Use appropriate variable names and proper class names. Trust me this is important. For example, Title and Content shouldnt be in `User` class, it more like to be in `Book` class.

Hope this enlightens you mate, cheers

Answer (score 0):

I see a potential problem with your code.
In your,

> listView.setOnItemClickListener(...) , onItemClick()

there is no code to actually launch the new activity.
You are only forming the `Intent`.

After,

> Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainContent.class);
>   intent.putExtra("noteId", Description);

You should add,

> startActivity(intent);

Hope that gets you sorted.